# If primary server's UTC source fails, how will synchronization be possible in NTP(network time protocol)?

Tags: distributed-systems, computer-networks

> If a primary server's UTC source fails, then it can become a stratum 2 secondary server. If a secondary server's normal source of synchronization fails or becomes unreachable, then it may synchronize with another server.

I have made a picture based on what I understood. I don't understand how will synchronization be possible when primary server source fails? Shed some light please here.

[image: Figure 1 shows UTC fails. Figure 2 shows primary server becoming secondary server]

Comment: Your question is unclear. In the title and in the quote, you are asking what happens when the *time source* of a stratum 1 server fails, but in the question body, you ask what happens when the *server itself* fails. Those are two very different things.

Comment: what will happen if time source fails?

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand how will synchronization be possible when primary server source fails?

It will happen exactly as before, except the time will not be accurate.

Comment: >If a primary server's UTC source fails, then it can become a stratum 2 secondary server. If a secondary server's normal source of synchronization fails or becomes unreachable, then it may synchronize with another server.

As I showed above, say UTC source fails and primary server becomes secondary server, how will it synchronize now? Any reading you recommend me to better understand this? Although I have learnt enough for exam point of view,would be nice to go that extra mile.

Comment: Criwgooscrow, how would you go about synchronising with another server? If your watch breaks, and we meet in the street, how would you synchronise with my watch?

Comment: @gnasher729 This is why I use stackexchange. I got it somewhat intituition.

>If a primary server's UTC source fails, then it can become a stratum 2 secondary server.

> If a secondary server's normal source of synchronization fails or becomes unreachable, then it may synchronize with another server.

That means it synchronizes with another secondary server. I got it now.